# Why dynamic focus(using JavaScript) is not working in iPad iOS 13+?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, voiceover

Dynamic focus using JavaScript is not working properly in iPad iOS 13+(Safari). Click events are also not triggering properly. Are there any major changes in executing JavaScript methods like element focus in the latest iOS for iPad. This is just happening in **iPad** only and not in iPhone.

Scenario: *I need to set focus on an input-box when selecting an item from the auto-populated list. Also, I'm checking this with voice-over in on state. So, I want it to read the value inside the input-box. The same feature is working fine in iPad iOS 12, but showing some weird behavior in iOS 13. Could anyone suggest me a workaround.*